# a very weird situation for the Latex Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

Tags: errors, classicthesis

I am using classicthesis download from latextemplate. It has main.tex and chapter01.tex. etc.... I got this error "Latex Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item" when I was writing in chapter04.tex. The log pointed me to the main.tex where the \include{chapter04} command is. I guess this is more complicated than just changing anything about this line.

Plus, I had not come across with any error before when I compiled main.tex with Chapter04. What made it REALLY weird is when I just randomly comment out (or delete) a paragraph in chapter04 or just change the font from 11pt to larger ones like 15pt, the error disappeared and main.tex compiled OK. It just seemed I have certain length (after typeset) of this chapter that Latex is not happy about...

I really dont understand this. since there are multiple files related to the issue and I frankly dont know which one went wrong or have conflicting issue, I just uploaded the zip folder containing all the relevant files.

[a dropbox link to my files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8soqcjh2bvhsai/latex_Leo.zip)

I would really appreciate any help for this urgent issue in my thesis writing.

Comment: Hello and welcome to tex SE. Please provide a _minimal_ example showing your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have `\\` in a section title using this documentclass.

works:

```
\section{How do lithium ions interact with OIPCs? --- A  Molecular Dynamics study}
```

doesn't work:

```
\section{How do lithium ions interact with OIPCs? \\ --- A  Molecular Dynamics study}
```

Comment: It depends on the document class. That is, on how `\section` is defined and possibly also how headers are defined and how the table of contents is defined. A `\\` in a section title can often work fine, but it does seem to be the source of the error in this document.

Comment: Is any way to have a line break in the section head?